# Seems my app taking so much battery after I implemented onDraw method

Tags: ondraw, android-custom-keyboard

After I have implemented a onDraw method to my custom keyboard app, it seems my app taking so much battery and ram. I just found a way to draw a circle in my keyboard by onDraw method which extends keyboardView. 
My onDraw class is below, Can someone take look at this.

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    healA = ddKeys_Master.autohealing;
    phealA = ddKeys_Master.autophealing;


    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

    //get all your keys and draw whatever you want
    List<Keyboard.Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();

    for (Keyboard.Key key : keys) {
        if (key.label != null) {
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#66cccc"));
            switch (key.codes[0]) {

                case 888:

                    if (healA && phealA) {
                        if (ddKeys_Master.healcount >= ddKeys_Master.autoHealCount) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ef0404")); //red
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else if (ddKeys_Master.healcount >= (ddKeys_Master.autoHealCount * 3 / 4)) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ef6904")); //orange
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else if (ddKeys_Master.healcount >= (ddKeys_Master.autoHealCount / 2)) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#efeb04")); //yellow
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else if (ddKeys_Master.healcount >= (ddKeys_Master.autoHealCount / 4)) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#09f247")); //light green
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#17a55e")); //green
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04;  light green #09f247; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);
                        }
                        if (ddKeys_Master.phealcount >= ddKeys_Master.autoPhealCount) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ef0404")); //red
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(37 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else if (ddKeys_Master.phealcount >= (ddKeys_Master.autoPhealCount * 3 / 4)) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ef6904")); //orange
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(37 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else if (ddKeys_Master.phealcount >= (ddKeys_Master.autoPhealCount / 2)) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#efeb04")); //yellow
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(37 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else if (ddKeys_Master.phealcount >= (ddKeys_Master.autoPhealCount / 4)) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#09f247")); //light green
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(37 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#17a55e")); //green
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04;  light green #09f247; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(37 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);
                        }
                    } else if (healA) {
                        if (ddKeys_Master.healcount >= ddKeys_Master.autoHealCount) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ef0404")); //red
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else if (ddKeys_Master.healcount >= (ddKeys_Master.autoHealCount * 3 / 4)) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ef6904")); //orange
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else if (ddKeys_Master.healcount >= (ddKeys_Master.autoHealCount / 2)) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#efeb04")); //yellow
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else if (ddKeys_Master.healcount >= (ddKeys_Master.autoHealCount / 4)) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#09f247")); //light green
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#17a55e")); //green
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04;  light green #09f247; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);
                        }
                    } else if (phealA) {
                        if (ddKeys_Master.phealcount >= ddKeys_Master.autoPhealCount) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ef0404")); //red
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else if (ddKeys_Master.phealcount >= (ddKeys_Master.autoPhealCount * 3 / 4)) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ef6904")); //orange
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else if (ddKeys_Master.phealcount >= (ddKeys_Master.autoPhealCount / 2)) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#efeb04")); //yellow
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else if (ddKeys_Master.phealcount >= (ddKeys_Master.autoPhealCount / 4)) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#09f247")); //light green
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);

                        } else {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#17a55e")); //green
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04;  light green #09f247; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(17 * scale, 17 * scale, 7 * scale, paint);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 901:
                    if (!ddKeys_Master.xprate) {
                        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#356dce")); //blue
                        //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                        canvas.drawCircle(key.x + (key.width / 2), key.y + (45 * scale), 4 * scale, paint);
                    }
                    if (ddKeys_Master.phealcount >= ddKeys_Master.autoPhealCount) {
                        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ef0404")); //red
                        //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                        canvas.drawCircle(key.x + (key.width / 2), key.y + (45 * scale), 4 * scale, paint);

                    }
                    break;
                case 903:
                    if (healA) {
                        if (ddKeys_Master.healcount >= (ddKeys_Master.autoHealCount)) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ef0404")); //red
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(key.x + (key.width / 2), key.y + (45 * scale), 4 * scale, paint);
                        } else {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#356dce")); //blue
                            canvas.drawCircle(key.x + (key.width / 2), key.y + (45 * scale), 4 * scale, paint);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 904:
                    if (phealA) {
                        if (ddKeys_Master.phealcount >= (ddKeys_Master.autoPhealCount)) {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ef0404")); //red
                            //orange #ef6904; yellow #efeb04; green #17a55e
                            canvas.drawCircle(key.x + (key.width / 2), key.y + (45 * scale), 4 * scale, paint);
                        } else {
                            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#356dce"));
                            canvas.drawCircle(key.x + (key.width / 2), key.y + (45 * scale), 4 * scale, paint);
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 906:
                    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#3d4754"));
                    canvas.drawCircle(252 * scale, 61 * scale, 17 * scale, paint);

                    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#2e3a42"));
                    canvas.drawCircle(252 * scale, 61 * scale, 16 * scale, paint);
                    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#b3cbdb"));
                    paint.setTextSize(12 * scale);
                    canvas.drawText(sTime, 252 * scale, 65 * scale, paint);
                    invalidate();
                    setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                            Paint paintt = new Paint();
                            float x = event.getX();
                            float y = event.getY();
                            float dx = Math.abs(x - (252 * scale));
                            float dy = Math.abs(y - (61 * scale));
                            float R = 17 * scale;//radius of circle.
                            if (dx > R) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Pressed outside");
                                return false;//outside
                            } else if (dy > R) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Pressed outside");
                                return false;//
                            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "Button Pressed Successfully");
                                return true;
                            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                                getOnKeyboardActionListener().onKey(666, null);
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    break;


            }


        }
    }

}
```

how can I make the code smoother to save battery?

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Comment: codes included with post.